# Distinct records for using SOQL query or some method

Tags: soql

```
list<Contact_Audit__c> aulitList =[SELECT Name, Changed_By_Name__c, Contact_ID__c, Changed_By__c, 
Changed_On__c, Change_Type__c FROM  Contact_Audit__c where  Contact_ID__c = 'xxxxxxx']
```

in this query Changed_On__c is list of employess emp1, emp2, emp3..

Change_Type__c captures last modifed by records, but i need a distinct record of employee based on
recent last modified by records 
Example

```
Changed_On__c--Change_Type__c
emp1 ------- 01
emp1 ------- 02
emp1 ------- 03
emp2 ------- 01
emp2 ------- 02
emp2 ------- 03
emp3 ------- 01
emp3 ------- 02
emp3 ------- 03
```

in this list i need only records like

```
Changed_On__c--Change_Type__c(date)
emp1 ------- 01
emp2 ------- 01
emp3 ------- 01
```

How can I get distinct records based on Change_Type__c

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to achieve. If you want to add a filter, just use the `WHERE` clause, for instance `WHERE Change_Type__c = '01'`.

Comment: It looks like he wants to arrange  records.So in such case use 'Order By' clause after where clause.
where  Contact_ID__c = 'xxxxxxx' order by Changed_On__c.

Comment: i need to get the list of employee single records based on recent last modified by Employee